# Where are Sources for Android 30

Tags: android, android-source, android-10.0

### Scenario

When I hit `ctrl+class name` to open the source code of a class, android studio usually opens a dummy implementation with stub methods. And when I lower `compileSdkVersion` to `29` those actions work correctly.

### Problem

I can't find `Sources for Android 30` in the `sdkmanager` window.

### Question

Will it be released soon or Am I missing something?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J0Mi.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will it be released soon

Usually the sources are not released until the production version of the OS ships. That should be later this year.

Comment: Thank you. I'll be waiting then

Comment: This messes up documentation.

Comment: @ravenisadesk: The Android 11 source code has not been released yet, so it will not show up on that site either right now.

Comment: @CommonsWare you mean even branch master is not the newest? Never notice before.

Comment: @ravenisadesk: Correct. They develop separately and push releases to public repositories at the point of the public release of that Android version. cs.android.com seems to be pulling from those public repositories. So, for example, `ControlsProviderService` is a new class in Android 11, and searching on it right now turns up no hits. In a couple of months, after Android 11 is released, cs.android.com should have the Android 11 sources indexed. While cs.android.com is new, this "throw the bits over the wall" approach to public Android releases is what Google has done since the beginning.